# Reading EnvironmentObject<T> outside View.body

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I constructed a BindableObject tied to my custom view.

I wanna update the array of items in this class

```
    // in my vm:

    class ViewModel {
        func fetched() {
            listView.listData.items = viewModel.listItems
        }
    }



    final class ListData: BindableObject {

        var didChange = PassthroughSubject<ListData, Never>()

        var items: [ListItem] = [] {
            didSet {
                didChange.send(self)
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a viewModel where I do my fetching because I would like to not have to inject a service into this ListData class. This is because I don't wan't it do any fetching I wanna keep that in my view model.

But when I try to update the ListData.Items in my VM I get this error:
    Reading EnvironmentObject outside View.body: file

Are you only allowed to update this variable inside the body of this new view class? In that case are you suppose to do all your network stuff inside a BindableObject?

Haven't found any documentation on the best practice of this yet.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out the best way to do that too, but the `Publisher` protocol (in **Combine** framework) seems promising.

Comment: My halfassed solution now is to make BindableObject init take a generic service. But it's tricky because I would rather not have network requests in that layer. I prefer to keep all my logic in my VM.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same question.  How do I transform an EnvironmentObject to use in a subsequent SwiftUI View?

Comment: the behavior of SwiftUI on iOS 13.0 regarding accessing state/environment outside of View body has changed in iOS 13.1 onwards, now you can access those vars from anywhere that references the View